# Springboot 2.2.5 and logging in file

Tags: spring-boot

i'm don't find the way to logging in file with spring 2.2.5

I tried in the application.properties
logging.file.name=C:/log/app.log
or 
logging.file.path=C:/log

But everytime it created the file, but don't write anything in.
Why ? I don't find any tutorial on web which work

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Comment: windows, i tried on linux server too and it's the same

Answer (score 0):

You can set the absolute path with following code

```
logging.path=D:\logs\logfile.txt
```

If the folder doesn't exist it gets created. On Windows you have to work with \ as seperator, while on Linux and Mac you need / as seperator. Check create dir and write permission on specified path.

You should either specify `logging.file` or `logging.path`, but not both ( when both are specified, logging.path is ignored and only logging.file is considered).

Comment: @Alexandre did you try this ?

Comment: I tried with a new application, simply generated from https://start.spring.io/ 2.2.6 with a @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 200)
    public void test() {
     logger.error("test2");
    }  and it the same, nothing is write in the log file. it was just created

Comment: Did you check permission issue ?